# Can't get a Windows Docker container to "run as administrator"

Tags: windows, docker, .net-core

I have a .NET Core app that's required to be "run as administrator" and I'm trying to get it to be built into a Docker image. I am able to build a Docker image just fine, but it fails at runtime with the "Need to run as Administrator" error.

Is there a way in the Dockerfile or in the docker run command to specify this? Does something else need to be added to the ENTRYPOINT where I'm calling "dotnet"?

Is this even possible?

Comment: What is the actual reason for running as administrator? What is the application actually trying to do? A good chunk of containers on hub.docker.com, for example, run as root. You use [`USER` in the dockerfile to switch users inside the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user).

Comment: It's a communications server that does quite a bit, so there's a lot of legacy code in there that accesses certificates, etc. It runs It's a windows build of a .net core app, so there's no concept of root - but I'll check out the USER command to see if an admin user will bypass this restriction. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I played around with the USER command in the Dockerfile, but could never get it to work with an admin user.

However, I found in a GitHub posting the mention of specifying the user in the docker run command like this did:

```
 docker run --user "NT Authority\System" ...
```

Which also works in the Dockerfile like so:

```
USER "NT Authority\System"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WORKDIR "C:\foldername" in dockerfile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).